# Work Item service limits: impossible to add more than 1000 links

Tags: azure-devops, settings, workitem, epic

on Azure DevOps, the Test Technical Team opened an Epic related to all the test cases, this Epic has reached the service limit of 1000 links added although the test cases related to the Epic are still ongoing and the team has many more links to add.

I tried, with Project Collection Administrator permissions,  to increase the service limit but unsuccessfully.
I searched among the documentation but nothing can help.
I'm dropping also a ticket on Azure Support.

Does someone know how to increase the service limit of 1000 links?
Otherwise, are there any suggested workarounds? as of now we only thought about opening a copy of the epic and using it as a clone to have another 1000 links to add.

Thanks in advance, kind regards,

Luca

Answer (score 0):

There is limit for `Work item links assigned to a work item` of 1000, according to the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/object-limits?view=azure-devops

You probably should change your process and way of working to match current limits as unfortunately it is highly likely not possible to adjust such limits. But you can try to raise a support ticket to the Microsoft Azure.

[image: Screenshot of documentation]

Comment: thanks for your reply! 
yes I'm definitely dropping a ticket requesting support!